# Adding Entity Framework to a Ranorex Project

Tags: entity-framework, ranorex

How can i add Entity Framework to a Ranorex Project ?

When i pressed add new item, all i can see is  class,  empty file , struct or interface

Thank you for your answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Ranorex is a .net extension library presumably you can add any library you wish to a project built in Ranorex studio.  You are correct Ranorex studio has only those options.  If you can't figure out how to reference the project in the studio, you could always open the project in Visual studio, and add it that way.  Ranorex gives you the sln file for the project, when you create a new ranorex solution